# What pros and cons of using a construct $({}) as a mediator in module design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, mediator

(Except the obvious dependency on jquery library of course.)
My reason: not to introduce new entities/code if it is possible to make as simple as it is.
E.g. example:

```
var app = {};
app.modules = {};
app.mediator = $({});

// response example
app.mediator.on( 'some-event', function ( e, data ) {
    console.log( 'gotcha!', data );
});

// module example
app.modules.module = ( function ( mediator ) {
    // event trigger example
    mediator.trigger( 'some-event', data );
})( app.mediator );
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: lets say: introduce a mediator to a jquery project with minimum code

Comment: What are you trying to do that jQuery custom events (with no new mediator object) can't already do?  jQuery custom events can already do subscribe, unsubscribe and trigger by themselves.

Comment: i don't want to fire those from any page html object(cause: i may remove those in future? etc). so, those are custom events indeed, and connected to something what i designate as a mediator(and what posses the whole event functionality - thanks to jquery.) to make it an obvious solution.